# Open PDFs in WebView

Tags: android, flutter, android-webview

I am trying to build an app using Flutter that uses the Webview to open a website. Within this website there are a number of pdfs and I want to open them inside the app as well, instead of redirecting to a browser or an acrobat viewer. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `pdfs and I want to open them inside the app ` Yes you can open them inside your app in PdfViewer but not inside  a WebView.

Comment: Thank you for your response! How exactly does that work? Can I open PdfViewer inside my webview? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: Inside your webview? Of course not. Inside a WebView one displays html or images.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Flutter, so I am still learning. I would really appreciate any help that I can get

Comment: I'm glad you appreciate my help ;-).

Comment: So are you saying that the I should code so that any pdf opens in the PdfViewer and then returns to WebView after I am done?

Comment: You can do what you want. Its not to me to tell you how your app should behave. You are free.